# Mapping strings from InputStream to ExecutorService

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, inputstream, iot

I'm implementing my `DIY` `IoT`. I have a central node (server) which receives the commands from different sources and executes them.

Input format:

```
<DEVICE_NAME>_<COMMAND> <DEVICE_NAME>_<COMMAND>  <DEVICE_NAME>_<COMMAND>
<DEVICE_NAME>_<COMMAND>  <DEVICE_NAME>_<COMMAND> 
<DEVICE_NAME>_<COMMAND>  <DEVICE_NAME>_<COMMAND>  <DEVICE_NAME>_<COMMAND>
```

Each line may contain multiple commands.

I have implemented a command executor server which takes the commands from the session as an `InputStream`. Then I split the data and process it:

```
private Device c0 = // Device constructor
private Device c1 = // Device constructor
private Device c2 = // Device constructor
private Device c3 = // Device constructor

private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

public void onConnection(InputStream in)     
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
    LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(isr);

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] strings = line.split(",");
        for (String raw : strings) {
            String command = raw.substring(0, 3);
            if (raw.startsWith("C0_")) {
                executor.submit(() -> c0.execute(command));
            } else if (raw.startsWith("C1_")) {
                executor.submit(() -> c1.execute(command));
            } else if (raw.startsWith("C2_")) {
                executor.submit(() -> c2.execute(command));
            } else if (raw.startsWith("C3_")) {
                executor.submit(() -> c3.execute(command));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand the code looks ugly. Do you have any improvement ideas? Maybe I could use `Steam API`?
Any hints/advices are appreciated.

UPDATE

I've tried to clean the code a bit by submitting the task only once, but the compailer sais the `device` must be `final` or `effectively final` so this does not work:

```
String command = raw.substring(0, 3);
Device device;
if (raw.startsWith("C0_")) {
    device = c0;
} else if (raw.startsWith("C1_")) {
    device = c1;
} else if (raw.startsWith("C2_")) {
    device = c2;
} else if (raw.startsWith("C3_")) {
    device = c3;
}
executor.submit(() -> device.execute(command));
```

Comment: Did you try to improve the code by yourself? Where did you reached so far?

Comment: Yes, I did. But without success full results.

Comment: I think there is a better place for such questions https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please post your intermediary code.

Comment: upadtedc the description

Comment: You are extracting the command via `String command = raw.substring(0, 3);`, which gives you precisely the part, you are checking via `raw.startsWith(…)`. That `command` string would work perfectly with `equals`, or a `Map` lookup, or a `switch` statement, to choose the right operation. I suppose, the actual argument to the operation should be `raw.substring(3)`…

Comment: The reason why the compiler complains in your last code snippet, is because `device` will not be initialized when all four tests fail. You have to handle that case with a last `else`, either assign a fall-back value to `device` or with a control flow statement which prevent the invocation of `submit` in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can map your commands like this:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(isr);

Map<String, List<String>> map = buffReader.lines()
            .map(s -> s.split(" "))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .map(s -> s.split("(?<=_)", 2))
            .collect(groupingBy(p -> p[0], mapping(p -> p[1], toList())));
```

**Update**

Actually you can combine both mapping and submitting:

```
// Register your devices
Map<String, Device> devices = new HashMap<>();
devices.put("c0", c0);
devices.put("c1", c1);
devices.put("c2", c2);
devices.put("c3", c3);
...

public void onConnection(InputStream in) {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
    buffReader.lines()
              .parallel()
              .map(s -> s.split(" "))
              .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
              .map(s -> s.split("(?<=_)", 2))
              .forEach(p -> executor.submit(
                      () -> devices.get(p[0]).execute(p[1])
               ));
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. But how can I submit the commands to the executor? Do I need to iterate over `map` ?